# Com_Contact strange behavior showing labels for empty contact fields, how to resolve?

Tags: component, jhtml, contact

So, thanks to FFrewin's help I was able to resolve and issue with the default com_contact template not showing entered address information [Problems with Contact showing](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21184/how-to-fix-address-not-displaying-on-default-com-contact-page) . The issue is that the contact template is still behaving strangely, specifically it is showing field labels (without icons) for empty fields. [image: empty fields]. I have the options to show both the phones and emails turned off both globally and on the specific menu item. So, other than hacking the template to strip the functions out, how can I address this?